# Remove zeros from matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a question and I hope it is not duplicate.

First, I have let say the following matrix:

```
A=[2 2 2 0 0
   1 2 3 0 0
   4 5 7 2 0]
```

I want to remove the zeros from A and return:

```
A=[2 2 2
   1 2 3
   4 5 7]
```

When I do

```
A(A==0)=[]
```

I get

```
A=[2 2 2 1 2 3 4 5 7]
```

Second, if instead of zeros I want to remove the elements that are greater than something. For example if I want to remove all elements greater than 6 (>6) of the following matrix B:

```
B=[2 2 2 5 3
   1 2 3 6 8
   4 5 7 2 1]
```

I get

```
A=[2 2 5
   1 2 6
   4 5 2]
```

P.S. I know how to do it using loops.

Comment: `A(:,find(all(A,1)))`

Comment: And what should happen with the 2 in the lower right corner?

Comment: @thewaywewalk I remove all the column whenever I find in it a 0.

Comment: For second problem - `B(:,~any(B>6,1))`

Comment: @Divakar why don't you write your comments as an answer so this question can be marked as 'answered'... Cheers.

Comment: @Floris, Done. I was expecting something better as my 100th answer :) Oh well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem solution**

```
A(:,find(all(A,1)))
```

**Second problem solution**

```
B(:,~any(B>6,1))
```

Comment: Congratulations on your 100th answer!